# Date overlap check in child table group by parentId in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, date-range

I have one ParentTable with example records as below.

```
Id =1,Name="ABC" 
ID=2,Name="DEF".
```

I have same as one ChildTable with example records as below.

```
   ID=1,ParentID=1,Fromdate='1/3/2015',Todate='1/5/2015'
   ID=2,ParentID=1,Fromdate='2/5/2015',Todate='31/5/2015' 
   ID=3,ParentID=2,Fromdate='1/3/2015',Todate='1/5/2015'
   ID=4,ParentId=2,Fromdate='4/5/2015',Todate='31/5/2015'.
```

Now,when I query with two date(one date range)e.g 1/5/2015-5/5/2015. I should get result of ParentId=1 record from ParentTable.Because In ChildTable,records with ParentId=1 contains a full passing daterange(1/5/2015-5/5/2015) but records with ParentId=2 doesn't contain date 2/5/2015 and 3/5/2015. I can use StoredProcedure or CTE. Can Any one help about this?

Comment: please format your codes please...

Comment: Due to Low reputation,It doesn't allow me use Image or anything to formate